# Is there a way to pass a string in the userAgent through testcaferc config file

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I am trying to pass a string as a part of userAgent from the testcaferc config file. I cant see it working somehow:

I have the following line of code in my testcaferc.json file:

```
 "browsers": [
        "Chrome:emulation:userAgent=TEST"
    ]
```

And in the test file, I have the following test:

```
test.page(`https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-is-my-user-agent/`)(`testing the user agent`, async t => {
        await t.debug()
    });
```

I cant see the userAgent getting set up by doing the above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you just have a typo in the browser name. You need to write `Chrome` in lowercase. Take a look at my config that works as expected:

```
{
  "browsers": [
    "chrome:emulation:userAgent=TEST"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Hey @Alex Kamaev, thanks for the reply. 

How to do this with device emulation please. 

Currently, the following does not work:


```{"browsers": ["chrome:emulation:device=iPhone X:userAgent=TEST"]}```

Comment: Try separating these options with a semicolon as described in the following documentation topic: [https://testcafe.io/documentation/403584/guides/intermediate-guides/mobile-devices-cloud-browsers-and-emulation#custom-device-guide](https://testcafe.io/documentation/403584/guides/intermediate-guides/mobile-devices-cloud-browsers-and-emulation#custom-device-guide).

Comment: Thanks for the response @Alex Kamaev. 

So, I tried separating the parameters as per the documentation.

When i try with userAgent, it just changes the browsers size to mobile, but the website is still in the desktop mode, for example: ``` "browsers": "chrome:emulation:device=iPhone X;userAgent=TEST" ``` 


And, If I dont pass a userAgent in the above browsers paramaters, then it loads the mobi website good. 

I tried this on https://www.google.com/maps/

Thanks.

Comment: You should not use the device option and the userAgent option simultaneously, since the device option already includes the correct user agent for iPhone X. In your case, these options interfere with each other.
You can try using the iPhoneX user agent (which is "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 11_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/604.1.38 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/11.0 Mobile/15A372 Safari/604.1") and modify it. However, in this case, the TestCafe team cannot guarantee that it will work correctly.